# Fetch new comments from firebase using a query

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a handleRefresh() function that is called when the user refreshes the page. When the refresh happens new comments that were posted are loaded into the tableview.

The problem i have is that when the users refreshes the data in the tableview loads twice so i get the updated comments but with duplicates where it has reloaded the old comments again.

I am a bit stuck on how to fix this.

Here is the code.

```
var CommentsQuery: DatabaseQuery {
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    let postKey = keyFound
    let postCommentRef = postRef.child(postKey)
    let lastComment = self.comments.last
    var queryRef: DatabaseQuery
    
    if lastComment == nil {
        queryRef = postCommentRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    } else {
        let lastTimestamp = lastComment!.createdAt.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        queryRef = postCommentRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp)
    }
    return queryRef
}


@objc func handleRefresh() {

CommentsQuery.queryLimited(toLast: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    
    var tempComments = [Comments]()
    let commentsSnap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments")
    let allComments = commentsSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    
    for commentSnap in allComments {
        let degree = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply degree").value as? String ?? ""
        let name = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply name").value as? String ?? ""
        let text = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply text").value as? String ?? ""
        let university = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply university").value as? String ?? ""
        let photoURL = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "reply url").value as? String ?? ""
        let url = URL(string: photoURL)
        let timestamp = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "timestamp").value as? Double
        let lastComment = self.comments.last
         
        if snapshot.key == lastComment?.id {
            
            let newComments = Comments(id: snapshot.key, fullname: name, commentText: text, university: university, degree: degree, photoURL: photoURL, url: url!, timestamp: timestamp!)
            
            tempComments.insert(newComments, at: 0)
            print("fetchRefresh")
        }
    }
    self.comments.insert(contentsOf: tempComments, at: 0)
    self.fetchingMore = false
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `self.comments.last` is persisted across page reloads, then it seems to be that the problem is that you use `queryEnding(atValue:` here:

```
queryRef = postCommentRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp)
```

Since timestamp values are incremental (higher values are newer), you want the node with a timestamp *higher* than the latest value, which you do with `queryStarting(atValue:` and not with `queryEnding(atValue:`.